# Flutter: FirebaseAuth Exception code channel-error

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, authentication

I am using firebase authentication in my app. When I try on debug mode or in apks, there is no problem. However, when I download my app from google play and try to login, when I enter the code that is sent by firebase with an sms, firebaseAuthException catches an error with the code channel-error. When I searched it in firebaseAuthExceptions, I could not find this error code. How can it be?

This is the code of catching code:

```
Future<AuthLoginResponse> login({required String code}) async {
    phoneCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: _verificationId ?? "", smsCode: code);
    if (phoneCredential != null) {
      try {
        final userCredential =
            await auth.signInWithCredential(phoneCredential!);
        return AuthLoginResponse(
            success: true, code: null, user: userCredential.user!);
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        print('ERROR: ${e.message} ${e.code}');
        return AuthLoginResponse(success: false, code: e.code, user: null);
      }
    } else {
      return AuthLoginResponse(success: false, code: null, user: null);
    }
  }
```

I tried these solutions:

- Added the sha keys of the app in google play store
- Upgraded all of the firebase packages.
- '''implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.2')'''

The problem is still continuing, and it does not occur always. Sometimes I can login sometimes not.

How can I fix it? Thank you.